# Clash between animate and hyperref on pdfLaTeX

Tags: hyperref, pdftex, pstricks, animate

When I compile the MWE below on `pdfLaTeX` I get the error message `` `! pdfTeX error (ext4): destinations cannot be inside an XForm. `` right before the `\newframe*` command is read. I have tried by switching the loading order of the `animate` and the `hyperref` packages, only to get the same error. Is there anyone out there who can provide any hints on what the problem is?

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{xifthen, ifpdf, ifxetex}
\usepackage[pdfcrop = { --hires }]{auto-pst-pdf} 
\ifpdf\else\usepackage{pstricks}\fi
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{animateinline}{2}
  \begin{pspicture}(0,0)(1,1)
    \psline(0,0)(0.5,0.5)
  \end{pspicture}
\newframe*
  \begin{pspicture}(0,0)(1,1)
    \psline(0,0)(1,1)
  \end{pspicture}
\end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some obscure reason, the combination of `hyperref`, `auto-pst-pdf` and `pstricks` places the pdfTeX built-in `\pdfdest` into `pspicture` environments.

`animate` uses `\pdfxform` to distill animation frames into PDF XObjects. `\pdfxform` fails if the content to be distilled contains pdf destinations.

The workaround below neutralises `\pdfdest` locally. It looks a bit hackish, but works.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{xifthen, ifpdf, ifxetex}
\usepackage[pdfcrop = { --hires }]{auto-pst-pdf}
\ifpdf\else\usepackage{pstricks}\fi
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\setlength\unitlength{1cm}
\begin{document}

\begingroup\def\pdfdest name#1#2{} %neutralise `\pdfdest'
\begin{animateinline}{2}
  \begin{picture}(1,1)
  \begin{pspicture}(0,0)(1,1)
    \psline(0,0)(0.5,0.5)
  \end{pspicture}
  \end{picture}
\newframe*
  \begin{picture}(1,1)  
  \begin{pspicture}(0,0)(1,1)
    \psline(0,0)(1,1)
  \end{pspicture}
  \end{picture}
\end{animateinline}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Comment: @{AlexG, Herbert}: Weeell... This answer would have been great one day ago (just kidding, it is great anyway). I have been working with the `standalone` package and followed Herbert's suggestion to use the `\animategraphics` command instead. Actually, I was going to ask him to turn his comment into a full-fledged answer, but now I think yours is what best fits my question and, besides, it is revelatory. Thanks indeed!